# Analytical Hankel transform of rational function (not computable with Mathematica or Maple)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

I need to compute the Hankel transform of an algebraic function that is not found in standard Hankel transform  integral tables. I tried to compute it exactly with Maple or Mathematica and also rubi, but all fail to deliver an exact solution. The numerical solution however is of course possible but not the anticipated solution.

The integral is
$$I(r;\tau,\epsilon):=\int_0^{\infty} dk k J_0(k r) f(k;\tau,\epsilon) $$
which is the Hankel transform of the function
$$ f(k;\tau,\epsilon):=\left(\frac{k^2 \tau  \epsilon +\epsilon }{k^4 \tau  \epsilon +k^2 (\tau +\epsilon +1)+1}\right)^p$$
where

- $p=1$ or $p=1/2$ (the square root of the given algebraic function), and
- the parameters $\epsilon$ and $\tau$ are reals with $\tau\geq 0$ and $\epsilon\geq 0$.

The function $f(k;\tau,\epsilon)$ is an approximation to the exact function
$$
f_{ex}(k;\tau,\epsilon):=\left(\frac{\epsilon \tau}{1+\tau + k^2 \epsilon \tau - e^{-k^2 \tau} I_0(k^2 \tau)}\right)^p
$$
from which we obtain $f(k;\tau,\epsilon)$ by using the Pade approximation for $e^{-k^2 \tau} I_0(k^2 \tau)\approx 1/(1+k^2 \tau)$. Of course the Hankel transform of the exact function $f_{ex}(k;\tau,\epsilon)$ is of similar interest.

Update:
Utilizing partial fraction decomposition on the Hankel transform function yields
$$ f(k;\tau,\epsilon)=\left(\frac{\alpha_+^2}{1+\beta_-^2 k^2}+\frac{\alpha_-^2}{1+\beta_+^2 k^2} \right)^p $$
with with four coefficients $\alpha_\pm(\epsilon,\tau)$ and $\beta_\pm(\epsilon,\tau)$.

With this we can calculate the $p=1$ case to
$$I(r;\tau,\epsilon)=\left(\frac{\alpha_+}{\beta_-}\right)^2K_0(r/\beta_-)+\left(\frac{\alpha_-}{\beta_+}\right)^2K_0(r/\beta_+)$$

The exact integral of the $p=1/2$ case is still unknown. Any tips and help would be of interest.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical about the possibility to find a closed form for these integrals in the general setting. Maybe in very special cases, like $\tau=\epsilon=0$, it is possible to obtain a result.

Comment: Yes, I can receive known analytical results for $\tau=0$, $\tau=\infty$, $\epsilon=0$ and $\epsilon=\infty$ but I would be interested in the general exact solution of the integral. The case $\epsilon=\tau$ would be also a step forward.

Comment: Do you have some reason to expect a closed-form solution to exist?

Comment: The numerical solution of the integrals for a large range of parameters looks fine. I can also obtain a closed solution for the case $p=1$ and $\epsilon\leq1$ together with $\tau\gg1$ with the help of Mathematica. On the other hand there exists a closed solution for $f(k;\tau,\epsilon)\approx (\frac{ϵ}{k^4 \tau \epsilon +k^2(\tau+\epsilon+1)+1})^{1/2}$ in "Tables of Integral Transforms" volume 2.